# Configurar Spring Boot com Swagger para gerar documentação a partir de um json

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Bom dia pessoal.

Eu estou documentando as APIs de um projeto utilizando Swagger2.

Nessa documentação ao invés de utilizar anotações é utilizado um arquivo json.
Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um projeto Spring Boot com Swagger 2, que utilize o json para documentar as APIs.

Pesquisei na internet e só encontrei esse tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/overcoming-swagger-annotation-overload-by-switchin?utm_content=bufferc0957&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Segui os passos descritos, mas não funcionou.

A única forma que consegui foi baixando a pasta dist do projeto https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist e apontando para o json, mas será que o Spring Boot não tem uma forma de configurar para que ele leia o json?

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de você trabalhar nesta situação.

API First: você possui o contrato desenhado primeiramente e deseja criar um scaffolding do projeto para Spring Boot. Para isso faça uso do [swagger codegen](http://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/).

Develop first: se você desenvolve a API e depois deseja criar um contrato para ela o framework [SpringFox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/) consegue te ajudar nesta situação.